# Ionic 3 Cordova InAppBrowser opens link in default browser and not in webview

Tags: ionic3, inappbrowser

I am trying to open google site in web view (InAppBrowser) but I am always getting option to choose in which browser link to launch. Am I missing anything

`inAppBrowser.create('https://www.google.com','_self','location=no,zoom=no');`

Thanks,

MSK

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing `_self` by `_system`

See https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/#cordovainappbrowseropen

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18518430)

Comment: I strongly disagree with you on this one